# Express Node.js and MQTT module modify DOM

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt

I'm trying to use a callback from the MQTT module to update an UL once it receives a new MQTT message .

If you can guide me to an example or show me an example that will be great.
Best regards,
Paul .

Comment: Hi @Paul Dumitru. Is this entirely within the browser (where the DOM is), or are you trying to do something on the server side (noting you've tagged the q with node.js and express). Assuming client side, there are lots of examples of how to programmatically update the content of the page (simple to do with jQuery for eg). There are (fewer) examples for how to receive MQTT messages in the browser via a websocket client (for example Paho).

Comment: Hello, @konelleary, at first I've tried to make it server side but with no success . The basic idea is to manipulate the DOM on receive . If I use paho than I'll have to give up using the mqtt module /